# How to change the contents of a div with a link click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a (Modified) jsfiddle of my webpage. It has quite a bit more, and the positioning is correct, as opposed to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ry0tec3p/1/

```
<a href="" class="btn1" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -640px; margin-top: 167px;">About</a>
```

Questions
Tutorials
Social

I'm trying to make the slightly transparent black area in the middle of the webpage (the "center" div.) change html when I click on one of the links above(which look like a few tabs on the webpage), and I want the tab to stay selected until another is clicked. It can't be just the text, because different tabs will have different HTML. Could somebody edit the jsfiddle, or show me how to, to make this happen?

EDIT:
I've tried using:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
```

$(".center").load( "file.html" );
});

which did nothing at all.

also,  I have looked into inner HTML, but my attempts at implementing it into this have failed because I'm ignorant.

Comment: Edited. Check the original.

Comment: So you want the button to load in external pages, are those pages named the same as the ID of the buttons pressed? If so you can target the button ID being click to set the name of the file you call.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to replace the contents of the "center" div to the contents of "about.html" when the button with the id "about" is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to run this locally it you may find it will not work, you must have this on a live server. **And on the same domain as the files you're calling for**

This is jQuery so make sure you have a script tag linked to jQuery!

**HTML**

```
<button id="home" class="Navigation">Home</button>
<button id="about" class="Navigation">About Us</button>
<button id="contact" class="Navigation">Contact Us</button>
<div id="PageData">Data Will Display Here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //All jQuery should go in this ready function
       //  Onclick function
        $('.Navigation').click(function () {   
      // this.id = to the ID of the element being clicked
        $('#PageData').load(this.id+".html");
        }); 
});
```

All you need to do it work this into your existing source code.
You can apply the `class="Navigation"` to any element you want to use to fire the function but it will use the `ID` of that element to load the page.

Example a button with the `id` of cars will try load `cars.html`

I hope this helps. Happy coding! :)

[**WORKING DEMO!**](http://coded4u.com/28461180/)

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I asked the owner of another website and he gave me a way of doing it. Thank you anyway though!

Comment: That's because it isn't for you to copy/paste. This does work but you have to insert the function to your website and set the class attributes to the elements you want or change the class in the function to fit. We don't do all the work for you, we help people debug their code and get it working. You can check it for yourself with the `Working Demo`