# display an html page in a div tag using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

I want to load an HTML page called Introduction.html( in the same folder as x.html) inside div1. But does not load. Here is the code snippet for x.html

**x.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("Introduction.html");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1"></div>

<button> 1.1 User</button>

<div id="cat" >
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Their is no error in the code i guess. No `CORS` issue. Just `#div1` does not have `height` and `width` to show content. That is what i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: This should work with/without a set height/width on the div. I have answered a question `like` this and no css used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461180/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-div-with-a-link-click/28463561#28463561

Comment: As its saying both the files are in same foler so how come the path is wrong/

Comment: yes @showdev, i respect that...

Comment: Nothing wrong with your source code. I have uploaded the exact source code here http://coded4u.com/28484654/ you can see it working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below is sample code to load any file in div element in HTML.

Sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#page1").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('page1.html');
              //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
            }); 
          });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type='button' value='Load Page1' id="page1">
      <div id="result" style="clear:both;">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Content of page1</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

After clicking Load Page, it will load content of page1.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `width` and `height` to this `div` in order to see some content i guess.

```
#div1
{
height:200px; 
width:200px;
}
```