# Linking to part of external .html within a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hyperlink, nav

So I have scoured the site and I can't find an answer to my question. I have a page with two divs. The left div contains an accordion menu that links to different pages that display inside the right DIV. I have used this example to load different external html files into the right DIV.

[How to change the contents of a div with a link click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461180/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-div-with-a-link-click/28463561#28463561)

Is there a way I can make the links link to specific parts of the page within the current div? When i use the method of adding a name to the anchor and then linking it as /nameofpage.html#anchorname , it targets it onto a blank page.

Here is how i have the nav setup

```
<li><a id="nameofpage" class="Navigation">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="nameofpage.html#link2">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="nameofpage.html#link3">Link3/a></li>
<li><a href="nameofpage.html#link4">Link4</a></li>
```

and here is how the HTML is on the external page loaded into the DIV

```
<h2 name="link1">Link1</h2>
<img>
<p></p>
<h2 name="link2">Link2</h2>
<img>
<p></p>
<h2 name="link3">Link3</h2>
<img>
<p></p>
<h2 name="link4">Link4</h2>
<img>
<p></p>
```

Comment: what do you mean from loading? do you use jquery to load?

Comment: if you use jquey to load content, You can trigger scrollTo (to your target element) inside the callback function of jquery load.

Comment: yes @AliSheikhpour i'm using jquery/ajax to load as shown in the example. how do I use scrollto link to an external html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function split the target into the page address and target anchor and triggers a scrollTop function after jquery load. Please notice that class name of **"menu"** and **onclick="return false"** are added too:

```
<a href="nameofpage.html#link1" class="menu" onclick="return false">link 1</a>
<div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        var mytarget=$(this).attr("href");
        var myarray=mytarget.split("#");
        var targetPage=myarray[0];
        var targetAnchor=myarray[1];
        $("#content").load(targetPage,function(){ 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+targetAnchor).offset().top}, 2000);
        ;});
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is a sample source of loaded page which includes the target anchor:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #emptySpace{height:800px;background:#aaaaaa}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="emptySpace"></div>
        <a id="link1">page scrolls here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```